# How to pause nivo slider when hovering over a certain non-slider div?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, nivo-slider

Well, the title says it all.
I want nivo slider to pause when hovering over the top menu in Twenty Fourteen theme. I'm struggling for hours now. Can't get it run...

Comment: Please post the code of what you have tried so far and if possible an working example.

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: It turns out that the question was put wrong. The point is that Nivo Slider has some nasty behaviour running under Twenty Fourteen theme. It turns out it isn't solvable with the pausing on hover. Since it's a different issue I'll start a new ticket. Thanks for you attention.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('nav li a').hover(function(){
 $('#Slider').data('nivoslider').stop();
});
```

Let me know if this works ;)

Comment: Thanks for creating some time trying to help me. See my comment under the question.